# Webgl highmap by displacement mapping according to brightness of texture

Tags: webgl, vertex-shader

I am new to webgl and opengl es ,below vertex shader show error that only produce a plan.The fragment shader is a typical one, it is not provided.

```
uniform mat4 modelview;
uniform mat4 transform;
uniform mat3 normalMatrix;
uniform mat4 texMatrix;
uniform sampler2D texture;
attribute vec4 vertex;
attribute vec4 color;
attribute vec3 normal;
attribute vec2 texCoord;
varying vec4 vertColor;
varying vec4 vertTexCoord;
const float zero_float = 0.0;
const float one_float = 1.0;
const vec3 zero_vec3 = vec3(0);
varying highp float height;


uniform float brightness;

void main() {
  //height =texture2D(texture,vec2(vertex.xz));
  //height =texture2D(texture,vec2(vertex.xz)).r;
  //gl_Position = transform * vertex;
    gl_Position = transform *vec4(vertex.x,vertex.y,brightness,1.0);
  vec3 ecVertex = vec3(modelview * vertex);
  vec3 ecNormal = normalize(normalMatrix * normal);
  vertTexCoord = texMatrix * vec4(texCoord, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

The above vertices shader fail showing highmap by using displacement mapping of brightness of texture image, and only displace a plane with texture
Please help how the vertices can shift from the surface of a sphere(original shape) to a higher position according to the brightness of the pixels of the textures.(show hills like on the surface of the sphere, the height of the hills are proportional to the brightness of pixels of the texture)

Answer (score 2):

You can't just move the position

imaging you have a 2x2 quad plane

```
A--B--C
| /| /|
|/ |/ |
D--E--F
| /| /|
|/ |/ |
G--H--I
```

Point E has a single normal facing perpendicular the plane but if you move Point E itself perpenticular to the plane suddenly it needs a different normal for each triangle that uses it, 6 triangles in the diagram above. And of course the normals of the other vertices need to change as well.

You'll need to compute new normals in the fragment shader either by using standard derivatives.

```js
function main() {
  const gl = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl');
  const ext = gl.getExtension('OES_standard_derivatives');
  if (!ext) {
    return alert('need OES_standard_derivatives');
  }

  const m4 = twgl.m4;
  const vs = `
  attribute vec4 position;
  attribute vec2 texcoord;

  uniform sampler2D displacementMap;
  uniform mat4 projection;
  uniform mat4 view;
  uniform mat4 model;

  varying vec3 v_worldPosition;

  void main() {
    float displacementScale = 10.0;
    float displacement = texture2D(displacementMap, texcoord).r * displacementScale;
    vec4 displacedPosition = position + vec4(0, displacement, 0, 0);
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * displacedPosition;
    v_worldPosition = (model * displacedPosition).xyz;
  }  
  `;

  const fs = `
  #extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives : enable

  precision highp float;

  varying vec3 v_worldPosition;

  void main() {
    vec3 dx = dFdx(v_worldPosition);
    vec3 dy = dFdy(v_worldPosition);
    vec3 normal = normalize(cross(dy, dx));
    
    // just hard code lightDir and color
    // to make it easy
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(vec3(1, -2, 3));
    float light = dot(lightDir, normal);
    vec3 color = vec3(0.3, 1, 0.1);
    
    gl_FragColor = vec4(color * (light * 0.5 + 0.5), 1);
  }
  `;

  // compile shader, link, look up locations
  const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);

  // make some vertex data
  // calls gl.createBuffer, gl.bindBuffer, gl.bufferData for each array
  const bufferInfo = twgl.primitives.createPlaneBufferInfo(
      gl,
      96,  // width
      64,  // height
      96,  // quads across
      64,  // quads down
  );

  const tex = twgl.createTexture(gl, {
    src: 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/images/heightmap-96x64.png',
    minMag: gl.NEAREST,
    wrap: gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE,
  });

  function render(time) {
    time *= 0.001;  // seconds

    twgl.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);

    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);

    const fov = 60 * Math.PI / 180;
    const aspect = gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight;
    const near = 0.1;
    const far = 200;
    const projection = m4.perspective(fov, aspect, near, far);

    const eye = [Math.cos(time) * 30, 10, Math.sin(time) * 30];
    const target = [0, 0, 0];
    const up = [0, 1, 0];
    const camera = m4.lookAt(eye, target, up);
    const view = m4.inverse(camera);
    const model = m4.identity();

    gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);

    // calls gl.bindBuffer, gl.enableVertexAttribArray, gl.vertexAttribPointer
    twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);

    // calls gl.activeTexture, gl.bindTexture, gl.uniformXXX
    twgl.setUniformsAndBindTextures(programInfo, {
      projection,
      view,
      model,
      displacementMap: tex,
    });

    // calls gl.drawArrays or gl.drawElements
    twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, bufferInfo);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
main();
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

or by looking at multiple points on the displacement map or

```js
function main() {
  const gl = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl');

  const m4 = twgl.m4;
  const vs = `
  attribute vec4 position;
  attribute vec2 texcoord;

  uniform sampler2D displacementMap;
  uniform mat4 projection;
  uniform mat4 view;
  uniform mat4 model;

  varying vec2 v_texcoord;

  void main() {
    float displacementScale = 10.0;
    float displacement = texture2D(displacementMap, texcoord).r * displacementScale;
    vec4 displacedPosition = position + vec4(0, displacement, 0, 0);
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * displacedPosition;
    v_texcoord = texcoord;
  }  
  `;

  const fs = `
  precision highp float;

  varying vec2 v_texcoord;

  uniform sampler2D displacementMap;

  void main() {
    // should make this a uniform so it's shared
    float displacementScale = 10.0;
    
    // I'm sure there is a better way to compute
    // what this offset should be
    float offset = 0.01;
    
    vec2 uv0 = v_texcoord;
    vec2 uv1 = v_texcoord + vec2(offset, 0);
    vec2 uv2 = v_texcoord + vec2(0, offset);
    
    float h0 = texture2D(displacementMap, uv0).r;
    float h1 = texture2D(displacementMap, uv1).r;
    float h2 = texture2D(displacementMap, uv2).r;
    
    vec3 p0 = vec3(uv0, h0 * displacementScale);
    vec3 p1 = vec3(uv1, h1 * displacementScale);
    vec3 p2 = vec3(uv2, h2 * displacementScale);
    
    vec3 v0 = p1 - p0;
    vec3 v1 = p2 - p0;
    
    vec3 normal = normalize(cross(v1, v0));
    
    // just hard code lightDir and color
    // to make it easy
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(vec3(1, -3, 2));
    float light = dot(lightDir, normal);
    vec3 color = vec3(0.3, 1, 0.1);
    
    gl_FragColor = vec4(color * (light * 0.5 + 0.5), 1);
  }
  `;

  // compile shader, link, look up locations
  const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);

  // make some vertex data
  // calls gl.createBuffer, gl.bindBuffer, gl.bufferData for each array
  const bufferInfo = twgl.primitives.createPlaneBufferInfo(
      gl,
      96,  // width
      64,  // height
      96,  // quads across
      64,  // quads down
  );

  const tex = twgl.createTexture(gl, {
    src: 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/images/heightmap-96x64.png',
    minMag: gl.LINEAR,
    wrap: gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE,
  });

  function render(time) {
    time *= 0.001;  // seconds

    twgl.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);

    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);

    const fov = 60 * Math.PI / 180;
    const aspect = gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight;
    const near = 0.1;
    const far = 200;
    const projection = m4.perspective(fov, aspect, near, far);

    const eye = [Math.cos(time) * 30, 10, Math.sin(time) * 30];
    const target = [0, 0, 0];
    const up = [0, 1, 0];
    const camera = m4.lookAt(eye, target, up);
    const view = m4.inverse(camera);
    const model = m4.identity();

    gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);

    // calls gl.bindBuffer, gl.enableVertexAttribArray, gl.vertexAttribPointer
    twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);

    // calls gl.activeTexture, gl.bindTexture, gl.uniformXXX
    twgl.setUniformsAndBindTextures(programInfo, {
      projection,
      view,
      model,
      displacementMap: tex,
    });

    // calls gl.drawArrays or gl.drawElements
    twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, bufferInfo);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
main();
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Note that rather than compute a normal from 3 samples of the texture you could probably precompute them at init time by going over the height map and generating a normal map. You could supply that as 3 channels of the same texture. Like say RGB = normal and A = height

```js
async function main() {
  const gl = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl');
  
  const m4 = twgl.m4;
  const v3 = twgl.v3;
  const vs = `
  attribute vec4 position;
  attribute vec2 texcoord;

  uniform sampler2D displacementMap;
  uniform mat4 projection;
  uniform mat4 view;
  uniform mat4 model;

  varying vec2 v_texcoord;

  void main() {
    float displacementScale = 10.0;
    float displacement = texture2D(displacementMap, texcoord).a * displacementScale;
    vec4 displacedPosition = position + vec4(0, displacement, 0, 0);
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * displacedPosition;
    v_texcoord = texcoord;
  }  
  `;

  const fs = `
  precision highp float;

  varying vec2 v_texcoord;

  uniform sampler2D displacementMap;

  void main() {
    // should make this a uniform so it's shared
    float displacementScale = 10.0;
    
    vec3 data = texture2D(displacementMap, v_texcoord).rgb;
    vec3 normal = data * 2. - 1.;
    
    // just hard code lightDir and color
    // to make it easy
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(vec3(1, -3, 2));
    float light = dot(lightDir, normal);
    vec3 color = vec3(0.3, 1, 0.1);
    
    gl_FragColor = vec4(color * (light * 0.5 + 0.5), 1);
  }
  `;

  // compile shader, link, look up locations
  const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);

  // make some vertex data
  // calls gl.createBuffer, gl.bindBuffer, gl.bufferData for each array
  const bufferInfo = twgl.primitives.createPlaneBufferInfo(
      gl,
      96,  // width
      64,  // height
      96,  // quads across
      64,  // quads down
  );

  const img = await loadImage('https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/images/heightmap-96x64.png');
  
  // get image data
  const ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
  ctx.canvas.width = img.width;
  ctx.canvas.height = img.height;
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  const imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, img.width, img.height);
  
  // generate normals from height data
  const displacementScale = 10;
  const data = new Uint8Array(imgData.data.length);
  for (let z = 0; z < imgData.height; ++z) {
    for (let x = 0; x < imgData.width; ++x) {
      const off = (z * img.width + x) * 4;
      const h0 = imgData.data[off];
      const h1 = imgData.data[off + 4] || 0;  // being lazy at edge
      const h2 = imgData.data[off + imgData.width * 4] || 0; // being lazy at edge
      const p0 = [x    , h0 * displacementScale / 255, z    ];
      const p1 = [x + 1, h1 * displacementScale / 255, z    ];
      const p2 = [x    , h2 * displacementScale / 255, z + 1];
      const v0 = v3.normalize(v3.subtract(p1, p0));
      const v1 = v3.normalize(v3.subtract(p2, p0));
      const normal = v3.normalize(v3.cross(v0, v1));
      data[off + 0] = (normal[0] * 0.5 + 0.5) * 255;
      data[off + 1] = (normal[1] * 0.5 + 0.5) * 255;
      data[off + 2] = (normal[2] * 0.5 + 0.5) * 255;
      data[off + 3] = h0;
    }
  }  

  const tex = twgl.createTexture(gl, {
    src: data,
    width: imgData.width,
    minMag: gl.LINEAR,
    wrap: gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE,
  });

  function render(time) {
    time *= 0.001;  // seconds

    twgl.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);

    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);

    const fov = 60 * Math.PI / 180;
    const aspect = gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight;
    const near = 0.1;
    const far = 200;
    const projection = m4.perspective(fov, aspect, near, far);

    const eye = [Math.cos(time) * 30, 10, Math.sin(time) * 30];
    const target = [0, 0, 0];
    const up = [0, 1, 0];
    const camera = m4.lookAt(eye, target, up);
    const view = m4.inverse(camera);
    const model = m4.identity();

    gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);

    // calls gl.bindBuffer, gl.enableVertexAttribArray, gl.vertexAttribPointer
    twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);

    // calls gl.activeTexture, gl.bindTexture, gl.uniformXXX
    twgl.setUniformsAndBindTextures(programInfo, {
      projection,
      view,
      model,
      displacementMap: tex,
    });

    // calls gl.drawArrays or gl.drawElements
    twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, bufferInfo);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

function loadImage(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.onload = _ => resolve(img);
    img.onerror = reject;
    img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
    img.src = url;
  });
}

main();
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```